Were the President and/or Marta actually more intelligent than Morty?
I think it is clear that the Morty "shards" are more like a merger between the game's view of the original NPC and Morty -- if they were only one five billionth of Marty's intellect, they would be non-functional.
So I think the original NPCs are given varying levels of intelligence. It was that intelligence that allowed Marta to conclude that they really weren't Jewish (hysterical idea to have them use Yiddish-sounding gibberish) and the President character to apparently have risen to that post (this is sort of implied, not that he started as president but was elected) and it took subjective years for that to happen.
